# Filtering rows is way slower in Hibernate than returning all rows

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate to implement card game stats and I want to optimize my query for loading duels from the database.

My entity relations are setup as follows:
A `duel` contains `player` 1 and `player` 2, each `player` contains a list of `duel card`s in the main `deck` and extra `deck`. Each `duel card` has a rarity and a `card`. Each `card` can have an `archetype` (or not).

Hibernate generates the following query for resolving the cards in player's decks:

```
select m1_0.deck_id,m1_1.id,c1_0.id,a1_0.id,a1_0.name,c1_0.card_id,c1_0.name,m1_1.rarity from deck_main_deck m1_0 join deck_card m1_1 on m1_1.id=m1_0.main_deck_id left join card c1_0 on c1_0.id=m1_1.card_id left join archetype a1_0 on a1_0.id=c1_0.archetype_id where m1_0.deck_id in(1207,58,59,110,111,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,462,463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,618,619,620,621,622,623,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,636,637,638,639,640,641,642,643,644,645,646,647,648,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,656,657,658,659,660,661,662,663,664,665,666,667,668,669,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719,720,721,722,723,724,725,726,727,728,729,730,731,752,753,754,755,802,803,852,853,854,855,856,857,858,859,860,861,862,863,864,865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880,881,882,883,884,885,886,887,902,903,904,905,906,907,908,909,910,911,912,913,914,915,916,917,918,919,920,921,922,923,924,925,926,927,928,929,930,931,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946,947,948,949,950,951,952,953,954,955,956,957,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014,1015,1016,1017,1018,1019,1020,1021,1022,1023,1024,1025,1026,1027,1028,1029,1030,1031,1032,1033,1034,1035,1036,1037,1038,1039,1040,1041,1042,1043,1044,1045,1046,1047,1048,1049,1050,1051,1052,1053,1054,1055,1056,1057,1058,1059,1060,1061,1062,1063,1064,1065,1066,1067,1068,1069,1070,1071,1102,1103,1104,1105,1106,1107,1108,1109,1110,1111,1112,1113,1114,1115,1152,1153,1154,1155,1156,1157,1158,1159,1160,1161,1162,1163,1164,1165,1166,1167,1168,1169,1170,1171,1172,1173,1174,1175,1176,1177,1202,1203,1204,1205,1206)
```

The issue with this query is that with a longer id list and a bigger duel table (which can have 1000s of rows), the query will become very, very slow. But, only on the Java side, running the query on PgAdmin 4 is pretty fast, however, around 21,000 rows are returned. This query does not fetch all decks at once, I'm already customizing the batch fetching sizes via `@BatchSize(size = XXX)` in my entity definitions for the deck lists.

When I run this query with `explain (analyze, buffers)` in PgAdmin 4, I get the following query plan:

```
"Gather  (cost=9928.27..23382.21 rows=21632 width=72) (actual time=215.012..510.135 rows=21427 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=10546"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=8928.27..20219.01 rows=9013 width=72) (actual time=130.749..402.611 rows=7142 loops=3)"
"        Hash Cond: (c1_0.archetype_id = a1_0.id)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=10546"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=8915.22..20182.14 rows=9013 width=62) (actual time=129.414..395.421 rows=7142 loops=3)"
"              Hash Cond: (m1_1.card_id = c1_0.id)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=10537"
"              ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=8658.20..19901.45 rows=9013 width=26) (actual time=122.704..380.588 rows=7142 loops=3)"
"                    Hash Cond: (m1_1.id = m1_0.main_deck_id)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=10315"
"                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on deck_card m1_1  (cost=0.00..10185.92 rows=402792 width=18) (actual time=0.013..81.695 rows=322234 loops=3)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=6158"
"                    ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=8545.54..8545.54 rows=9013 width=16) (actual time=121.051..121.053 rows=7142 loops=3)"
"                          Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1280kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=3963"
"                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on deck_main_deck m1_0  (cost=1.25..8545.54 rows=9013 width=16) (actual time=52.449..117.443 rows=7142 loops=3)"
"                                Filter: (deck_id = ANY ('{1207,58,59,110,111,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,462,463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,618,619,620,621,622,623,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,636,637,638,639,640,641,642,643,644,645,646,647,648,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,656,657,658,659,660,661,662,663,664,665,666,667,668,669,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719,720,721,722,723,724,725,726,727,728,729,730,731,752,753,754,755,802,803,852,853,854,855,856,857,858,859,860,861,862,863,864,865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880,881,882,883,884,885,886,887,902,903,904,905,906,907,908,909,910,911,912,913,914,915,916,917,918,919,920,921,922,923,924,925,926,927,928,929,930,931,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946,947,948,949,950,951,952,953,954,955,956,957,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014,1015,1016,1017,1018,1019,1020,1021,1022,1023,1024,1025,1026,1027,1028,1029,1030,1031,1032,1033,1034,1035,1036,1037,1038,1039,1040,1041,1042,1043,1044,1045,1046,1047,1048,1049,1050,1051,1052,1053,1054,1055,1056,1057,1058,1059,1060,1061,1062,1063,1064,1065,1066,1067,1068,1069,1070,1071,1102,1103,1104,1105,1106,1107,1108,1109,1110,1111,1112,1113,1114,1115,1152,1153,1154,1155,1156,1157,1158,1159,1160,1161,1162,1163,1164,1165,1166,1167,1168,1169,1170,1171,1172,1173,1174,1175,1176,1177,1202,1203,1204,1205,1206}'::bigint[]))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 237193"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=3963"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=155.34..155.34 rows=8134 width=44) (actual time=6.636..6.637 rows=8134 loops=3)"
"                    Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 672kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=222"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on card c1_0  (cost=0.00..155.34 rows=8134 width=44) (actual time=0.864..2.636 rows=8134 loops=3)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=222"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=7.47..7.47 rows=447 width=18) (actual time=1.310..1.311 rows=447 loops=3)"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 30kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=9"
"              ->  Seq Scan on archetype a1_0  (cost=0.00..7.47 rows=447 width=18) (actual time=1.012..1.109 rows=447 loops=3)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=9"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=44"
"Planning Time: 4.240 ms"
"Execution Time: 513.047 ms"
```

It seems like PostgreSQL does a good job at optimizing the query. I'm still wondering if I can add any additional optimizations such as indexes? PostgreSQL indexes primary keys by default so that's already taken care of.

**Why does Hibernate parse the result rows so slowly?**
If I reduce the duel count fetched per query (e.g. working with [`Pageable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html)s and looping manually), the row parsing time seems to decrease significantly but the performance is still not great, reading 1000s of duels will take minutes. I was hoping to reduce this time to seconds since performance and a reasonably low memory footprint are both crucial for my use case. Note that I'm using standard CRUD repository methods such as

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Duel.withPlayers", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Duel> findAllByGameMode(final GameMode gameMode, final Pageable pageable);
```

It's also strange that just fetching all is way faster:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Duel.withPlayers", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Duel> findAll(final Pageable pageable);
```

Filtering out rows by e.g. game mode is enormously slower. How does that make sense? The returned row count is even higher than in the previous query but Hibernate processes it way faster anyway.